# Missing File in Gem after Build

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

**TL;DR:**

Don't run bundle within an existing git repository.  Weird things will happen without any error messages.

**Original Question:**

I've built a gem by adapting the steps in this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/gem-creation-with-bundler/

As a final step, I've run gem build .gemspec

This succeeds, but when I install the gem I find the critical file, the one which contains my code, isn't in the gem.  Another file in the same (lib) directory, "version.rb", does exist in the gem.

I don't know how to start debugging this...how does bundler/gem build decide which files to include in the gem?

**Edit:**

My workflow is:

```
gem build <project_name>.gemspec
gem unpack <project_name>
=> confirm file does not exist in <unpacked>/lib/

gem install <project name>
=> confirm file structure in ~/home/stefan/.rvm/... contains gem, but does not contain desired file
```

**Edit 2 / Resolution**:

I was finally able to get this working by committing all my code to a remote repository, creating a clean clone, and building the gem.  The new gem included all the required files.

A bit of history...I originally created the code and committed it before thinking about making a gem (this is my first gem).  I then used bundle *inside* the original repository, which didn't complain, but was probably the reason for the weirdness.

Comment: I have confirmed with a gem on my system that using `gem build project_name.gemspec; gem unpack project_name-x.y.z.gem` should include and unpack a recently-added file, and no additional work or checks are normally required. I cannot tell from your workflow description what might be causing the difference from expected behaviour.

Comment: This probably saved me 10 hours of bashing my head against a brick wall. I love Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One of the things bundler did for you is start a local git repo to version-manage your gem code. Check that you have added the file in git

```
git add lib/gem_name/missing_file.rb
```

Bundler generated gems use git internally to track "membership" of source files for the gem. You can see this in the .gemspec where it uses backticks to call out to git and generate a file list:

```
gem.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
```

Note this also means you should pay attention to what you list in `.gitignore`

Comment: The file was missing from git.  However I've now added it and rebuilt the gem.  Same result.  I've also done a git ls-files, which does show the file, and all my test files.  None of these are included in the gem.

Comment: Are you using rake tasks to install the gem? `rake install` does a `gem build` and `gem install` using managed locations. `gem build name.gemspec` does not do an install, it just creates `name-x.y.z.gem` in the current folder

Comment: Question updated with workflow. I've never used rake install, but I'm sure the file doesn't exist in the original gem prior to installation

Comment: I'm not sure what else could be going wrong for you. `gem build` should package all files listed in the `.gemspec`, it doesn't have any alternative way to know which files to include. Think it's worth checking: Are you using the gemspec as-is, when it was created by `bundler`? Are you certain you are picking up the latest build file (do an `ls` and check date/time after running build, in case this is just mistaken identity on the file)? Not saying you are doing these wrong, just it's an odd error, and I don't have anything better (yet)

Comment: See updated question for resolution.  I've accepted your answer since it was helpful in understanding how bundle works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had this issue as well and simply using git add to put the new file in the repo took care of it for me entirely. I believe I did run bundle install at some point as well.