# Gem development can't add new file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm having what seems to be some very basic problems getting started with Gem development in ruby.

I've created a new project with this command.

```
bundle gem foobar
```

I can now run

```
bundle && bundle exec rake spec
```

and everything is fine.

However I try to add a new part to my spec

```
expect(Foobar::BAR).not_to be nil
```

and then define this in ./lib/foobar/error.rb

```
module Foobar
  BAR="bar"
end
```

It just does not find this file. Error is `NameError: uninitialized constant`. I can `require_relative` in `spec_helper.rb` but that's clearly not right or sustainable.

I've seen the issue here [Missing File in Gem after Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922322/missing-file-in-gem-after-build) I've added the new file to git. That does not help, adding the files directly in the gemspec file does not help either.

The whole project is here https://github.com/ollyjshaw/broken_gem

What am I doing wrong? It's gotta be something trivial, but I can't see it.

**Answer:** 
Answer is in Antony's comment
"You're not requiring your error file when your gem is loaded: github.com/ollyjshaw/broken_gem/blob/master/lib/foobar.rb#L1" 
"You'd load your main module and that module would load other modules/classes it needs and down the tree it goes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd add all the class/module files to the load path in the `spec_helper.rb` file:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__)
require "your_gem"
```

Comment: That seems to be the way that the default mini test based gem is set up. That doesn't work either. With this skeleton gem, the foobar gem is required. Bundler attempts to provide this from the local source. So in test helper starts with `require 'foobar'`. https://github.com/ollyjshaw/broken_gem/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb It brings in the other files ok, just not the new one

Comment: You're not requiring your error file when your gem is loaded: https://github.com/ollyjshaw/broken_gem/blob/master/lib/foobar.rb#L1

Comment: You'd load your main module and that module would load other modules/classes it needs and down the tree it goes.

Comment: Oh man, I knew it would be a face palm. Thank Anthony! My only saving grace is I don't develop in ruby for the day job :-)