# require works for all files in same directory except one

Tags: ruby, rubygems

In a personal gem project "rubellite", I have added a new file "enumerator.rb", but require isn't working for that file. Other similar files in the same directory are successfully required.

Why is this specific require not working?

My gem's folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

The contents of `rubellite/lib/rubellite.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'rubellite/array'
require 'rubellite/enumerator'
require 'rubellite/float'
require 'rubellite/hash'
require 'rubellite/integer'
require 'rubellite/object'
require 'rubellite/prime'
require 'rubellite/regexp'
require 'rubellite/string'
require 'rubellite/symbol'
require 'rubellite/time'
require 'rubellite/timer'

require 'rubellite/version'
```

Each of these requires works *except* for `require 'rubellite/enumerator'`. When building and installing, I get `cannot load such file -- rubellite (LoadError)` (...) `cannot load such file -- rubellite/enumerator (LoadError)`.

Similarly, if I go to `rubellite/lib` and go into Pry, I get this:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'rubellite/enumerator'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rubellite/enumerator
from /Users/willcross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
[2] pry(main)> require 'rubellite/string'
=> true
[3] pry(main)> require 'rubellite/array'
=> true
[4] pry(main)> require './rubellite/enumerator.rb'
=> true
```

I figure `[4]` is the key to this problem, but I can't for the life of me wrap my head around why it would just be this one file.

And fwiw, the contents of `rubellite/lib/rubellite/enumerator.rb`:

```
class Enumerator
  def diff
    reduce(:-)
  end

  def prod
    reduce(:*)
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems like you have the legacy version of this gem installed on your gem search path. In any case, when dealing with a subdirectory, one better use `require_relative` to avoid issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem wasn't quite what I thought it was.

The actual problem:
After building and installing the gem, my `enumerator` file *didn't exist* in the install folder (`/Users/willcross/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/rubellite-1.1.1`).

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922322/missing-file-in-gem-after-build), I discovered that, because my file was untracked, gemspec skips over it.

The solution:
I committed my changes in git and rebuilt/reinstalled the gem and it works now. I've flagged this as a duplicate, but am also answering it so others may potentially learn from my mistakes :)